# How can I use user defined variables and `USE`?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have some schemas, all with the same format. The format is: schema name, underscore, single digit (example: database_1).
How can I loop through all of these schemas easily? I tried `SET @num = 1; USE database_@num;` But it says

> Unknown database 'database_@num'

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.30

Comment: Having a bunch of 'identical' databases (or tables) is usually a bad way to design the schema.  Rather than finding a _solution_ to `database_@num`, let's discuss getting rid of the _problem_.

Comment: Can you suggest a good place to discuss such issues?

Comment: Start a new question.  Explain the purpose of having `database_nnn`.  Tell us what kind of data (shopping, scientific, time series, etc) that you have.  Ask for performance advice on fetching from different databases due to the split you decided on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular statement you want to run - `USE` - is not supported by dynamic SQL. I therefore suspect what you want to do is not currently possible.

If dynamic SQL did support the `USE` statement, you could have done:

MariaDB 10.1:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('USE database_', @num);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`
```

MariaDB 10.3:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('USE database_', @num);
```

Both result in:

> ERROR 1295 (HY000): This command is not supported in the prepared
>   statement protocol yet

The MariaDB knowledge base has [a list of permitted statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepare-statement/#permitted-statements) that you can `PREPARE`. Effectively, this is a list of statements that can be used in dynamic SQL.

**EDIT:**

So instead I suppose you're left with options such as:

1. Generate your statements as text -- un-roll your loop to a long list of statements, dump them to a .sql file and then `SOURCE` that file.
2. Use a scripting language such as Python, bash, PHP etcetera. Do the loop in the scripting language. (Do not use prepared statements for the `USE` statement, obviously.)